# javascript setTimeout function out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call showUpload(); from within two setTimeouts. Neither works. It seems to be out of scope and I'm not sure why. I tried `this.showUpload()` which didn't work either.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var progress_key = $('#progress_key').val();

            // this sets up the progress bar
            $('#uploadform').submit(function() {
               setTimeout("showUpload()",1500);
               $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value:0}).fadeIn();
            });


            // uses ajax to poll the uploadprogress.php page with the id
            // deserializes the json string, and computes the percentage (integer)
            // update the jQuery progress bar
            // sets a timer for the next poll in 750ms
            function showUpload() {
                $.get("/myid/videos/uploadprogress/" + progress_key, function(data) {
                    if (!data)
                        return;

                    var response;
                    eval ("response = " + data);

                    if (!response)
                        return;

                    var percentage = Math.floor(100 * parseInt(response['bytes_uploaded']) / parseInt(response['bytes_total']));
                    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value:percentage})

                });
                setTimeout("showUpload()", 750);
            }
        });
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Daniel said, this should work:

```
setTimeout(showUpload, 750);
```

Please note that the quotes should be removed (this is why it isn't being executed until the timeout runs out).  Right now, you are passing a string, which is `eval`ed when the timeout runs out.  This `eval` will happen in a different scope, which is why you are seeing the problem you are seeing.

Instead, passing a reference to the `showUpload` function to `setTimeout` will allow your function to be executed later.  Keep in mind that when it runs, it will be in a different scope, so you may have other scope issues, like with `progress_key`.  You will need to create a closure around showUpload to capture that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to remove the parenthesis from `showUpload` in both your `setTimeout` calls. Otherwise you will be invoking the `showUpload` method instead of passing it as a parameter:

```
setTimeout(showUpload, 750);
```

Comment: The intent is right, though the description is a bit off, you're calling the method with the parenthesis, but you're trying to invoke a method in the global space when it's a string...where it doesn't exist, the direct reference like you have is the correct approach.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for the note... I was just looking for some references on how `setTimeout()` evals code when passed as a string.